# Fullcalendar calendar.getEvents() doesn't return JSON event sources just loaded

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, fullcalendar-5

I'm having an issue with using calendar.getEvents() within the loading function. In v3 the code looked like this:

```
$('##calendar').fullCalendar({
...,
events: {
    url: 'myurl',
    ...
},
loading: function(bool) {
$('##loading').toggle(bool);
if (!bool) {
    var eventview = $('##calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
    var loadedEvents = $('##calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(events){ return (moment(events.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD') >= eventview.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')  && eventview.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') > moment(events.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))});
    for (i = 0; i < loadedEvents.length; i++) {
... // I inventory the type of events in the current month here
    };
}, ... }
```

and now with v5 it looks like this:

```
"var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
 ...,
eventSources: [{
    url: 'myurl',
    ...
}],
loading: function(bool) {
    if (!bool) {
        var eventview = calendar.view;
        var loadedEventTypes = new Array();
        var loadedEventTypesHTML = ''; var loadedEventTypesStyles = '';
        var loadedEvents = calendar.getEvents(); // filter removed for debugging

        for (i = 0; i < loadedEvents.length; i++) {
...
        };
    },
 ... }
```

While the docs say that in v3 clientEvents and in v4/5 getEvents both " ... return an array of Event Objects that FullCalendar has stored in client-side memory." that's not what I'm seeing.

In the v3 code clientEvents does retrieve the events just loaded via the JSON url however in v5 getEvents is returning the the event array before loading the json via the url provided; the getEvents event set does not include the JSON just loaded ( and on display). It does holds events fetched before the last json call. The first time the page loads the array is empty even though the events are on display in the calendar.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get at the events just loaded and on display in v5.

Is this a bug in FullCalendar?

Comment: `in v5 getEvents is returning the the event array before loading the json via the url provided`...that's expected. Makes everything more asynchronous and perform faster. `loading` is not the tool for whatever job you want to perform - which isn't clear...what exactly do you want to do with this data?

Comment: This does seem like a bug. `loading` docs say "Triggered with false when done.". How then does it make sense for `getEvents` to return outdated results if I'm calling a callback that's triggered by the event loading finishing? In my case, it's actually loading the events from a *previous* calendar that was removed from the DOM, which doesn't even make sense. It's like it's using a central pool to store event data and can't differentiate between what events are associated with what calendars. It can be """fixed""" by adding a `setTimeout` wrapping the call to `getEvents`, but that smells.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do something with your events after load, I think you should take a look at [Event Render Hooks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks) and more over at eventDidMount instead of loading.

Comment: but this will be triggered as many as count of your events, and  make the render process slow.